# Error catching integers in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
strFName = ""
while strFName != strFName.isalpha():
    if strFName != strFName.isalpha():
        strFName = input("What is your first name? ")
    else:
        print("Your name cannot contain numbers")
    break
```

I want the user to enter their name, but if they enter any letters the program will throw up an error. So far I am trying to do this with a try and except but whenever I enter a number it just goes straight on to the next part of the program.

Comment: Please read the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 0):

You mean the first name cannot contain digits?
If so, you can do something like this:

```
import string

has_digits = lambda x: any([i.isdigit() for i in x])

first_name = "0"
while has_digits(first_name):
    first_name = input("Enter first name (cannot contain digits): ")

print('Your name is {}'.format(first_name))
```